# Dice Rolling Simulation

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm wondering how I could get my dice rolling simulator to stop when it your total roll is one of 2 certain numbers, (example: rolling will stop when you reach a total roll of 7 or 12). Here is my code so far:

```
public class RollDice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        int dice1;   // First Dice.
        int dice2;   // Second Dice.
        int total;   // Sum of the two rolls. 

        dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
        total = dice1 + dice2;

        System.out.println("Your first roll is " + dice1);
        System.out.println("Your second roll is  " + dice2);
        System.out.println("Your complete roll is " + total);

    }  

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just wrap everything with a `do-while` loop:

```
int total;   // Sum of the two rolls. 
do {
    int dice1;   // First Dice.
    int dice2;   // Second Dice.

    dice1 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    dice2 = (int)(Math.random()*6) + 1;
    total = dice1 + dice2;

    System.out.println("Your first roll is " + dice1);
    System.out.println("Your second roll is  " + dice2);
    System.out.println("Your complete roll is " + total);
} while (total != 7 && total != 12);
```

Or something to that extent. :)

See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

Comment: For some reason it won't let me resolve total as a variable in the last line, why is this?

Comment: Ah right, sorry about that, typing too fast. Answer edited.. :)